# attributes with a local (file://) src not working when html file served statically via Node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am new to node.JS, and have been working on a simple client-server connection, where an index.html file is served to the user on localhost. My index.html file works perfectly when opened without server, but as soon as I serve them via node, any image, iframe, or script with a local src breaks.

For a visual, I have the following in index.html:

```html
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello!</h1>
<img src="doggy.png"/>
</body>
</html>
```

My node file (server.js) serves the file with the below code:

```js
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/html' })
  fs.createReadStream('index.html').pipe(res)
})

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000)
```

with the overall result being the heading of Hello! being displayed on localhost:3000, but the image not working.

I am sure this problem is related to my relative inexperience with node, and not anything inside the html, maybe it is even intended behaviour because of security policies? I am hoping someone can address this in a way I can understand, and maybe even give some solutions, I'd be happy to upvote anyone who would put such time into it.

Comment: That is by design.

Comment: So is there any way to serve the file to the user?

Comment: A web page cannot access the client's local filesystem. ???!!!?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are serving your website with an HTTP server, like NodeJS, you should use the same server to give the assets or referenced resources to the browsers like CSS, JS and other linked files.

The following code is used to do it. The idea is make a middleware so serve the statics file that are used for the html files.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');

const BUILDPATH = path.join(__dirname);

const { PORT = 3000 } = process.env;

const app = express();
app.set('port', PORT);

app.use(express.static(BUILDPATH));
app.get('/*', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index.html', { root: BUILDPATH }));

const httpServer = http.createServer(app);

httpServer.listen(PORT);
console.info(` Client Running on: http://localhost:${PORT}`);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I would upvote, but @Kevin B 's downvote brought my reputation too low (I need 15 to cast votes)

Comment: In the meantime, I have accepted the answer. (I'll make sure to come back and upvote when my reputation's back).